# Conservation of Energy Question (train example)

Tags: classical-mechanics

So we have a train going 5 m/s that gets loaded with 20,000 kg of coal while going over a 10m platform for 2 s. There is a 50,000 N horizontal force applied to the train during that period in order to keep the train going a constant 5 m/s.

That 50,000 N force does 500,000 J of work. But the KE of the coal at the end of the platform is only 250,000 J and the KE of the train itself (minus the coal) is unchanged. Where does the other 250,000 J go?

Answer (score 0):

The addition of coal essentially constitutes as a series of inelastic collisions. Therefore, kinetic energy will be lost. The energy loss comes from work done by internal forces between the coal and the train.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. If the coal were brought up to speed with elastic collisions they would keep bouncing around. Would it be right to model that situation as half the balls moving +5 m/s and half -5m/s in the frame of the train, and so half moving 0 m/s and half 10 m/s in the earth frame. So the KE of the perfectly elastic coal would be 1/2 * 1/2 * 20,000 kg * (10 m/s) ^2 = 500,000 J?

Answer (score 0):

> Where does the other 250,000 J go?

It dissipates to thermal energy and vibrations. It is surprising that it is half of the total energy, but basically as the coal lands in the train it experiences kinetic friction to accelerate. This friction warms the coal.

Comment: True. My apologies for being so nitpicky